# Java exception handling with try catch

Tags: java, return, finally

```
public class ReturnValueFromTryCatchFinally
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(methodReturningValue());
    }

    static String methodReturningValue()
    {
        String s = null;
        try
        {
            s = "return value from try block";
            return s;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            s = s + "return value from catch block";
            return s;
        }
        finally
        {
            s = s + "return value from finally block";
         //  return s;


        }
    }
}
```

If we run this program then we are getting output as "return value from try block". If we remove the comment from the `finally` block (`return s;`) then we are getting output "return value from try block return value from finally block".

Why isn't it giving the output "return value from try block" and "return value from try block return value from finally block"? Because first it will return from the `try` block then it goes to `finally`.

Answer (score 3):

A function can't return twice. It's going to return one string or the other. It can't return both.

One of the two `return` statements will "win out" and decide what gets returned. As you can see from your testing, if a `finally` block has a `return` statement it overrides the return value from the `try` block.

If you're wondering why the `finally` block has no effect when the `return` statement is commented out, it's because in the `try` block returns the return value is (provisionally) set to "return value from try block". It is *not* set to "the value of `s`, whatever that may be". Updating `s` later in the `finally` block doesn't retroactively change the return value of the `try` block. It's already been locked in. The `finally` block can only change the return value if it has its own `return` statement.

For what it's worth, it is a very, very bad idea to have a `finally` block with a `return` statement. When an exception is thrown you want that exception to propagate to the caller. A `return` statement in a `try` block is skipped when there's an exception, but in a `finally` block it will be executed unconditionally and cause the exception to be suppressed. **Don't put `return` inside of `finally`.**

Comment: Most IDEs will warn you if you put `return`, `break`, `continue` or `throw` inside a `finally` block. It's also against numerous coding guidelines such as https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/ERR04-J.+Do+not+complete+abruptly+from+a+finally+block . Also, in C#, it's a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, a method returns only **once**. And the finally branch is executed just after your inner 'return s'.